# How to show existence of conformal Atlas for surfaces.

Tags: geometry

I've started to learn some basic differential geometry. I'm reading "Elementary Differential Geometry" by Andrew Pressley. I found this theorem in the book which is not proved I was wondering if any one can give me references or help me with the proof. Thanks.

Theorem: Every surface has an atlas consisting of conformal surface patches.

Answer (score 0):

In "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces" even Do Carmo does not deal with that theorem, but he refers to L. Bers, "Riemannian Surfaces", New York University, Institute of Mathematical Sciences, New York, 1957-1958, pp. 15-35.